# What constitutes a package for nosetests?

Tags: python, package, code-coverage, nose, nosetests

I've written a "package" -- by which I mean a directory with an `__init__.py` in it -- called `ardid`:

```
(master)dbliss@nx3[ardid]> ls
analysis.py   ardid.sh     __init__.pyc    plot_support.py   utils.py
analysis.pyc  goals.py     k_12.png        plot_support.pyc  utils.pyc
ardid.py      goals.pyc    plot_ardid.py   results/
ardid.pyc     __init__.py  plot_ardid.pyc  tests/
```

As you can see, the package contains the following modules

- `analysis`
- `ardid`
- `goals`
- `plot_ardid`
- `plot_support`
- `utils`

as well as test modules in the directory `tests`.

(`__init__.py` is empty.)

However, when I run `nosetests` with `--cover-package=ardid`, the output shows coverage only for a few of `ardid`'s modules (specifically `ardid`, `goals`, and `utils`):

```
(master)dbliss@nx3[ardid]> nosetests tests -s --cover-package=ardid --with-coverage
...............
Name             Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
----------------------------------------------
ardid.py             0      0   100%   
ardid/ardid.py     108     54    50%   105-254
ardid/goals.py      42     38    10%   52-87, 102-161
ardid/utils.py     437    366    16%   23-26, 30-71, 78, 83-89, 108-110, 113-140, 142-146, 165-166, 168-183, 186-218, 223-285, 288-324, 344, 357-427, 438-441, 443-444, 446-468, 475-480, 483-496, 499, 508-509, 512-513, 516-524, 532, 545-548, 559, 571, 575-576, 581-582, 594-605, 614-615, 618-1018
----------------------------------------------
TOTAL              587    458    22%   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 15 tests in 11.454s

OK
```

Why is this?

Note that it is not the case that these are the only modules for which I have tests:

```
(master)dbliss@nx3[ardid]> ls tests/
test_plot_support.py  test_plot_support.pyc  test_utils.py  test_utils.pyc
```

What is true is that the `ardid` module imports `goals` and `utils`, but does not import the other modules.  Is this what's causing `nosetests` only to detect `goals` and `utils` (in addition to `ardid`)?  Why would this be?

I think the answer may have to do with the way I'm importing the package modules in my test modules.  Because the `ardid` module has the same name as the package, I have to import it with

```
from ardid import ardid
```

(If I were to call simply

```
import ardid
```

the package would be imported.)

The other modules I import with, e.g.,

```
import utils
```

Comment: Are there tests covering the files that are excluded? What is in `__init__.py`?

Comment: What happens if you go *"up"* one level in the directory structure and run the same command there?

Comment: Consider restructuring such that the `tests` and `ardid` directories are at *the same level*, within another dictionary (that you can also call `ardid`). Then run the tests from *that* directory.

Comment: *"Better"* how? Have a look at e.g. http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/ for setting up a new project.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry for the confusion.  i thought the definition of "better" was obvious in that context: better as in not requiring a restructuring of the project simply in order to get the desired `nosetests` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nosetests` considers part of the package `ardid` modules that are imported from `ardid` (from `ardid` the package, not the module).

Thus, one simple solution is to change the imports in the test modules to

```
from ardid import X
```

where `X` is one of the modules to be tested.

Another solution, which would be more appropriate if this package were intended for use by anyone other than me (and which subsumes my solution), is provided by @jonrsharpe in the comments.